Is it possible to change the sequence backing an identity column?
After a machine malfunction and a hurried transfer of data onto another machine, we have somehow ended up with some brand new sequences replacing old sequences as the backing for identity columns (and for some old serials).
We can RESET the new sequences with the maximum values in the tables, and also use ALTER SEQUENCE ... RENAME to rename the new sequences to the old names (to get around any hard-coding in the client code) but I was wondering if it was possible to swap the old sequence back in place instead?

serial columns are just a bundle of loosely tied Postgres features. See:

Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)
Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns

It's easy to swap out the underlying SEQUENCE. And it's ok to do so:
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN tbl_id
SET DEFAULT nextval('the_old_seq');

ALTER SEQUENCE the_old_seq OWNED BY tbl.tbl_id;  -- optional, really

-- possibly drop the other sequence that just got ousted?
-- but make sure it's not used by anything else

serial column and SEQUENCE are "friends with benefits" in a manner of speaking. Table and sequence have separate access control lists (GRANT privileges), which causes (caused) a lot of confusion.
IDENTITY columns are the later, standard SQL iteration of (almost) the same concept. Here, the SEQUENCE is tied more closely to its IDENTITY column. It's a mere implementation detail, like a unique index is an implementation detail of a PRIMARY KEY constraint. A "marriage" in a manner of speaking. No separate ACL lists. And it's not ok to swap out the SEQUENCE underneath, even if still possible with superuser privileges.
Related:

How to change a table ID from serial to identity?

All details (including commands to manipulate system catalogs) in this blog post by Peter Eisentraut, the original author of the IDENTITY feature:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/

